# Add auto increment column to an existing table ordered by created time

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below table in Oracle db (ATP db)

```
create table record(
 record_id raw(16) primary key,
 dataset_id raw(16) not null,

 name varchar2(127) not null,
 time_created timestamp not null,
 CONSTRAINT record_fk_dataset_id foreign key (dataset_id) references dataset(dataset_id),) 
partition by reference (record_fk_dataset_id);
```

I would like to add new auto-increment column id in sequence with time_created, eg. records are created in this order of time_created 1st record at 02/12/2021 12:37:37 PM 2nd record at 02/12/2021 12:40:45 PM

1st record to get id as 1 and 2nd id as 2.

I have some data in record table already.

**Edit:**
time_created can have duplicate entries too.

Comment: Do you want this just for display when you query the table - which can be a contiguous list, via `row_number()` - or as a value to be stored in a column in the table? Auto-increment/identity columns use sequences, which can have gaps and aren't necessarily issued in order (RAC and caching), so keeping a strict relationship wouldn't be simple. What are you going to use this for, and how strict/accurate does it need to be? And how is the created time set, as that doesn't have a `default` clause?

Comment: @AlexPoole I would want it store in db table, later I can also make it unique or primary key. This auto incremental id will be maily used in pagination (curser pagination approach), time_created is the time when a new record is created, time_created can have duplicate values.

Comment: Gaps (from sequence caching, or deletion) could make pagination a bit inconsistent. Using a ranking function might make more sense - there are lots of examples of doing that - though it could be slower potentially.